# How does Facebook Messenger draw a chathead? (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-imageview, android-windowmanager

I know this has already been asked a lot of times here on StackOverflow, but I'm fascinated how Facebook Messenger draws the Chatheads.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) to place an ImageView as an overlay. However, dragging it around is **very** sluggish, unlike Chatheads which show extremely smooth animation.

Turning on the "Show GPU view updates" option in Developer options flashes the screen while a Chathead is being dragged. However, dragging my ImageView doesn't trigger any flashing.

Here's a small screencast: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13595927/temp/TRIM_20140225_134543.mp4

I tried setting the layer type to `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`, but it didn't change anything. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

my chathead like facebook messenger :
https://github.com/henrychuangtw/FB-ChatHead

- Dragging and Bounce animation
   
  [image]
- Messenger : show text and sendtext
   
  [image]
  [image]

  - LongPressing to Stop
     
    [image]

Comment: Updating the chathead's position through LayoutParams is sadly not as fluid as Facebook has managed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

here is my simple solution: 
1)  Create a Service (don’t forget to add it in Manifest.xml).

2)  Add ImageView (or other View) which you want to be drawn on your window. You must specify exactly the place on the screen via initialization of LayoutParams.

3)  Add OnTouchListener to the View you want to move and then calculate in MotionEvent.ACTION_UP (this is when you drop the View) when you must remove it from the screen (in my case when the crumpled paper is in the recycle bin).

4)  Don’t forget to add in your Manifest.xml the following code snippet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

5)  Don’t forget to remove all the views you’ve drawn in onDestroy() in your Service:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // remove views on destroy!
    if (ivCrumpledPaper != null) {
        mWindowManager.removeView(ivCrumpledPaper);
        ivCrumpledPaper = null;
    }

    if (ivRecycleBin != null) {
        mWindowManager.removeView(ivRecycleBin);
        ivRecycleBin = null;
    }
}
```

6)  Here you are the result:

[image: Dismiss message]

7)  I created a blog post which contains more details and full code - [here](http://blog.dision.co/2016/02/01/implement-floating-widget-like-facebook-chatheads/)

Comment: Sorry, but this technique isn't even remotely close to the smoothness of Facebook's implementation :)

Comment: I know its been almost 6 years, but any chance your code is still available? @Stefan