# Overlay only on the home screen on Android (similar facebook chatheads)

Tags: android, overlay, homescreen

I need to place the overlay on the home screen (like facebook chatheads). But under some specific conditions I want to display an overlay only above the home screen BUT UNDER all other screens.
Is it possible to implement this?

For the implementation of the chatheads I use [this tutorial](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) and this [sample app](https://github.com/fouady/SpotifyTray-Android).

Comment: PopupWindow class could help you.

Comment: I've implemented such kind of widget. Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35130405/5814524