# How to make a button that draws over any screen?

Tags: java, android

Apps like [Floating Toucher](https://web.archive.org/web/20171030210410/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boatmob.floating.touch) or [Link Bubble](https://web.archive.org/web/20170223125925/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkbubble.playstore) proves how useful a floating button can be. And no, I'm not talking about FABs as per Material Design guidelines here, I meant a literally 'floating' button that draw over any screen in the system that can be dragged around and clicked.

Take a look at these examples:

[image]
<sub>(source: [boatmob.com](http://www.boatmob.com/download/floatingtouch/feature1.jpg))</sub>

Now, I tried to Google a way to do this but I'm afraid I'm still at lost here. How can these apps draw over screens outside their own?

I've come across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) which more or less asking about a similar question. But to be honest, I wasn't able to gain much information from it. Said question mainly addressed how to intercept a touch for a floating view; Not how to specifically make one.

I really hope that somebody out there could enlighten me on this. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: I've implemented such kind of widget. Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35130405/5814524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about an activity's view (not Widgets), 'floating' on screen, like Facebook ChatHeads. Then you should create a background service and attach a view with it. Though it is not recommend by Android.

See below links

[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/